# How to exempt specific rows from filter excel 2017?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

So I have several tables I combined into one and I want to keep specific rows as month separators.

I want the filters to work as normal except I want them to ignore each header row.

Is this possible with or without a customer VBA macro?

Here is an image of an example with the desired results after filter.

[image]

Comment: How about just including the "headers" (really data rows in the relative to the actual filter rows) in your filter criteria.

Comment: @gns100 The spreadsheet is sent to several managers and the idea is that the manager should only need to select their name in the filter on the left and be able to see the results as shown in the 2nd table on the attached image in my question. Currently I have the header rows as an extra filter option that the managers need to select along with their name so they will show properly.

Comment: So you'll either need vba (google will give you the base VBA to start with) or consider altering the spreadsheet so that each row employee has the month attached (then delete the month header).

Comment: @gns100 the month header is required. So I will probably need to look into VBA. I was hoping to avoid that as I am a decent python programmer but I have not spent much time looking at VBA.

Comment: A different solution - Have a new sheet, with a drop-down menu of manager's names. When they select their name, it populates the sheet with all of the data they need, in the same format, with the headers included. This will take some fairly complicated excel wizardry, but it is doable with just Excel, no VBA needed